# lighttpd with "php fastcgi" send output to console instead of browser

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd

I have a php script running as fastcgi server that executes browser-requested php files (why not use php/php-cgi? because of [performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208903/auto-load-function-class-libraries-when-needed), we used APC too, but still not good enough):

```
# cat myphpcgi
#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php

<?php

while (Accept() >= 0) {     # simple wrapper of FCGI_Accept from FastCGI dev-kit
    $file = GetRequestFile();   # get requested .php file name(like /var/www/htdocs/a.php)
    if ($file == FALSE)
    continue;
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($contents == FALSE)
        continue;
    # remove heading <?php and trailing ?>
    $contents = ltrim($contents);
    $contents = rtrim($contents);
    $start = strpos($contents, "<?php");
    $start += 5;
    $end = strrpos($contents, "?>");
    $end -= 2;
    $ct = substr($contents, $start, $end);
    # execute the requested file
    eval($ct);
}

?>
```

By using above cgi script, function/class libraries will be loaded only once(using 
require_once).

The script is started by：

```
# /usr/local/lighttpd/bin/spawn-fcgi -f /var/www/cgi-bin/myphpcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8888
```

And lighttpd is configured like this:
...

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
                    ("localhost" =>
                      ( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                        "port" => 8888,
                      )
                    )
                 )
```

...

But when browser asking for a.php as below:

```
<?php
require_once "bigfunction.php"
echo "haha";
printf("hehe");
?>
```

The cgi script outputs "hahahehe" to the system console instead of to the browser.

```
# hahahehe
```

If I wrapper the FCGI_printf function (from FastCGI devkit too) and use it to print out
strings, the result will be sent to the browser, this is a solution, but existing code will need to make changes.

I've also tested with Apache and the output simply goes to apache's error_log. Maybe a 
dup2() will solve the problem but I didn't find the fd that FastCGI devkit uses.

P.S. __autoload won't save our time as most of includes are functions and constants.

P.S.2 dup2() won't solve the problem:
from the output of strace of the cgi script:

```
write(1, "haha", 4haha)                     = 4
write(1, "hehe\n", 5hehe)                   = 5
write(3, "\1\6\0\1\0\0\0\0\1\3\0\1\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 24) = 24
shutdown(3, 1 /* send */)
```

where fd 3 is the connection with lighttpd, when I added dup2(3, 1), got 500 error on browser, and lighttpd's log shows:

```
2011-05-24 13:09:54: (mod_fastcgi.c.2443) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 0 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:8888
2011-05-24 13:09:54: (mod_fastcgi.c.3237) response not received, request sent: 834 on socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:8888 for /large.php , closing connection
```

P.S.3: code for Accept():

```
PHP_FUNCTION(Accept)
{
    int n = FCGI_Accept();
    RETVAL_LONG(n);
    return;
}
```

code for GetRequestFile():

```
PHP_FUNCTION(GetRequestFile)
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *p = NULL;
    int ret;

    // apache and lighttpd has different name
    p = getenv("PATH_TRANSLATED");
    if (p == NULL) {
        p = getenv("SCRIPT_FILENAME");
        if (p == NULL) {
            RETVAL_BOOL(0);
            return;
        }
    }

    memcpy(buf, p, strlen(p));
    buf[strlen(p)] = '\0';
    RETVAL_STRINGL(buf, strlen(buf), 1);
    //dup2(3, 1);
    return;
}
```

P.S.4 When add a wrapper for FCGI_printf like below:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(Myprintf)
{
    char *str;
    int str_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &str, &str_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    char *p = emalloc(str_len + 1);
    memcpy(p, str, str_len);
    p[str_len] = '\0';
    FCGI_printf("%s", p);
    efree(p);
    return;
}
```

Using Myprintf() to print strings, when myphpcgi works together with apache, it works fine and the string is displayed on the browser. But when using lighttpd, the string goes nowhere, interesting...

Comment: Please add the code of `Accept()` and `GetRequestFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the FCGI wrapper yourself to offer FCGI for PHP.

Instead you should use the existing wrapper to execute PHP scripts as FCGI. It works with any existing PHP code.

---

Instead of eval, just include the file:

```
# remove heading <?php and trailing ?>
include($file);
```

Probably this ensures that require_once will work as expected.

Comment: Where can I find the "existing wrapper"? The functions defined in sapi/cgi/fastcgi.h are not exported to user space.

Comment: Indeed if I change the first line of the cgi script from "#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php" to "#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php-cgi", everything works fine but "bigfunction.php" will be loaded for every request.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer regarding that. Let me know if that solves the issue. I now better understand what you're looking for, cool idea ;)

Comment: Same result as eval(). require_once works if php is used in the cgi script.

Comment: cgi does mean having shebang `#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php-cgi` or by not using your wrapper?

Comment: cgi means using shebang #!/usr/local/php5/bin/php-cgi

Comment: Wrapper of FCGI_printf works fine with apache but lighttpd. coded added in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

@hakre Finally this problem is solved by hacking phpsrc/sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c.
The reason is that php's echo and printf functions' behavior are controlled
by different sapis, like cgi, cli, the sapi determines where the destination
is. Modules are not able to change the destination.

In cgi_main.c, the original work flow is:

```
listen();
while (req = accept()) {
    php_request_start();
    php_execute_script();
    php_request_shutdown();
}
```

All I did is move the request start and shutdown out of the while loop,

```
listen();
php_request_start();
while (req = accept()) {
    php_execute_script();
}
php_request_shutdown();
```

It works fine and the "require_onced-files" will be loaded only once.